# Get all the frames from video

Tags: ios, swift, avassetimagegenerator

I'm trying to get all the frames from some video but it seems that instead of getting 255 different frames I'm getting like 8 different frames but each of these 8 frames repeated 30 times.

my code is (the problem is with imagesForVideo array):

```
    imagesForVideo = []
    imagesForVideoCGI = []
    var timesArray:[NSValue] = []

    let generator:AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: sourceAsset)

    for var i = 0; i < numberOfFrames - 1; i++ {
        var actualTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
        let duration:CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(i), Int32(30))
        let frameRef:CGImageRef = try! generator.copyCGImageAtTime(duration, actualTime: &actualTime)
        let tempImage:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: frameRef)
        let nsDuration = NSValue.init(CMTime: duration)
        timesArray.append(nsDuration)

        imagesForVideoCGI.append(frameRef)
        imagesForVideo.append(tempImage)
    }
generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes(timesArray, completionHandler: {(_, im:CGImage?, _, _, e:NSError?) in self.addingImages(im)})
```

and

```
func addingImages(im: CGImage?) {

    if let img = im {
        imagesForVideoCGI.append(img)
        let justImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)
        imagesForVideo.append(justImage)
    }
    else {
        print("Fail")
    } 
}
```

What did I wrong here?

Comment: let duration:CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(i), Int32(30)). timescale should be 1 not 30

Comment: But why? `CMTimeMake(a, b)` is the time value `a/b`. I need to pass to `copyCGImageAtTime` the real time position for the frame I needed, and it should be numberOfTheFrame/fps, right?

Comment: fps has nothing to do with the time scale

Comment: have you find the solution ? @lithium